# Goで文字列の間と最後に文字を挿入したい

Tags: go

Golangで文字列、例えばAAAAAAの間にABABABABABABのように別の文字列を挿入したいです。もちろん、for文で回して実装できますが、スピードを求める場合利用できる関数などはありますか。
自分は`strings.FieldsFunc`が使えると考えやってみましたが、できませんでした。もしあれば教えて下さい。
https://play.golang.org/p/kAcWCHBPfK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regexp.ReplaceAllString()` を使ってみました(`A` を挟んでいます)。

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    a := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    re, _ := regexp.Compile(`(.)`)
    replaced := re.ReplaceAllString(a, "${1}A")

    fmt.Println(replaced)
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。

Answer (score 4):

KoRoN さんの別解ですが。

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func InsertEach(s string, t string) string {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    for _, r := range s {
        if b.Len() > 0 {
            b.WriteString(t)
        }
        b.WriteRune(r)
    }
    return b.String()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(InsertEach("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "A"))
    fmt.Println(InsertEach("あいおえおかきくけこさしすせそ", "～"))
}
```

for-range string はコピーが発生しない点、bytes.Buffer を使っているのでアロケーションを最小限に抑えられる点を重視してみました。

Answer (score 3):

スピード重視ならば、正規表現を使わずにunicode/utf8を使って自前でやるというのも、選択肢になります。日本語への対応が要らなければ、[]byteを直接いじるのでも良いでしょう。

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func InsertEach(s string, t string) string {
    ls, lt := len(s), len(t)
    r := make([]byte, 0, (lt+1)*ls)
    for i, w := 0, 0; i < ls; i += w {
        _, w = utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[i:])
        if len(r) > 0 {
            r = append(r, ([]byte(t))...)
        }
        r = append(r, s[i:i+w]...)
    }
    return string(r)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(InsertEach("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "A"))
    fmt.Println(InsertEach("あいおえおかきくけこさしすせそ", ","))
}
```

出力

```
aAbAcAdAeAfAgAhAiAjAkAlAmAnAoApAqArAsAtAuAvAwAxAyAz
あ,い,お,え,お,か,き,く,け,こ,さ,し,す,せ,そ
```